# Background color for column in kableExtra does not work

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex, kable, kableextra

A column in a table should have a background color. Somehow with my code this doesn't work. Here a (hopefully) reproducable example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
temp2 <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]
```
```{r, results='asis'}
cat(
  kableExtra::kbl(
    x = temp2,
    format = "latex",
    digits = 2,
    col.names = NULL,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    position = "h",
    toprule = NULL,
    bottomrule = NULL,
    linesep = ""
  ) %>%
    kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width = TRUE) %>%
    kableExtra::column_spec(column = 2, background = "green") %>%
    kableExtra::row_spec(row = nrow(temp2) - 2, hline_after = TRUE) %>%
    kableExtra::row_spec(row = nrow(temp2) - 1, bold = TRUE, extra_latex_after = "\\hline \\hline")
)
```
````

As you can see in the output the cells are marked with `\cellcolor{green}` but in the pdf output the column is not green. Also I can see in the output that the first row of the colored column has not this tag `\cellcolor{green}`, which will be most likely my next problem. Does anybody have a suggestion how I can make this code work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: when the `full_width = TRUE` is removed the column gets coloured but not for the first row (as expected). But this does not really solve my problem, because I would like to have the table in full width.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  Maybe you can refer this to the kableExtra [issue list](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will file it there.

Comment: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/660